# error: incompatible types: Collection<DB_Account> cannot be converted to Collection<Account>

Tags: java, generics, unchecked, incompatibletypeerror

The following gives this error:

```
public class Account
{
    ...
}

public class DB_Account extends Account implements DBObject
{
    ...
}

public class Cache<E extends DBObject>
{
    protected Map<Long,E> m_contents;

    ...

    public Collection<E> values()
    {
        return m_contents.values();
    }
}

public class DB_Imp implements Database
{
    protected Cache<DB_Account> m_accounts;

    ...

    @Override
    public Collection<Account> getAccounts()
    {
        if (m_accounts.isValid())
            /* Compiler gives error here */
            return m_accounts.values();
        ...
    }
}
```

I've currently worked around the compiler error in the `DB_Imp` class by adding a `Collections.class.cast()` around the call to `accounts.values()` and added a `@SuppressWarnings`. There must be a better way. The other way is to modify the Cache class to:

```
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T> Collection<T> values()
    {
        return Collections.class.cast(m_contents.values());
    }
```

Comment: What version of Java? They've improved type inference in Java 8, and the above gives no warnings here.

Comment: javac 1.8.0_45

Without the cast the compiler gives an error not a warning. However with the cast the `Collection<DBAccount>` could be assigned to an `Collection<Monkey>`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is List<Dog> a subclass of List<Animal>? Why aren't Java's generics implicitly polymorphic?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your trying to return a `Collection<DB_Account>` as a `Collection<Account>` an the compiler wont' let you. `Collection` is not covariant, so `Collection<DB_Account>` is not a subtype of `Collection<Account>`.

The way to fix this would be to modify the method `values` in `Database` to:

```
Collection<? extends Account> values();
```

**EDIT:**
  If you can't make that change, what I'd do instead is:

```
@Override
public Collection<Account> getAccounts() {
    if (m_accounts.isValid())
      return Collections.unmodifiableCollection(m_accounts.values());
    ...
}
```

This creates an unmodifiable view of `values()` with the right parameter type (`Collection<Account>`). And it gives you the extra security (at runtime) that your `Cache` can't be modified by client code. `values()` returns a view of the `Cache` map, so every change made to it by someone calling `getAccounts()` would reflect on the `Cache`. This is something you'd generally want to avoid.

Comment: Unfortunately that would be rewriting an existing libraries API

Comment: Edited my answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

First look at the error. It is saying that:

- For `Cache<DB_Account> m_accounts`, the method call `m_accounts.values()` returns a `Collection<DB_Account>`.
- Ands `getAccounts()` returns `Collection<Account>`
- But these are not polymorphic: `Collection<Account>` is **not a supertype** of `Collection<DB_Account>`, and so the compiler cannot convert them.

This is completely correct and expected.

- For a supertype `X`
- And subtype `Y`
- `Foo<Y>` is **not a subtype** of `Foo<X>`

This is a crucial concept in Java's generics, and worth understanding. You should read [The Java Tutorials > Generics, Inheritance and Subtypes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/inheritance.html).

#### Possible solutions

It is hard to suggest a solution without knowing the exact context. One possible approach, if you are able to change the `Database` interface, would be to change `getAccounts` to use a wildcard

```
public Collection<? extends Account> getAccounts();
```

However this would only allow you to get items out of the returned `Collection`, not set them into it (maybe this is what you want). To understand why you should read ["Upper Bounded Wildcards"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/upperBounded.html) and ["Guidelines for Wildcard Use"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcardGuidelines.html).